# Can't log back onto Server 2012?

Tags: windows-server-2012

I logged into Server 2012 on our domain with my administrator account through a remote desktop connection.  I locked the computer to do some other things and now when I try to log back in it tells me I need to be added to Remote Desktop Users to log back in.  This is odd because I was just logged in, I check AD and I indeed am in the RDU group.  I remove myself and re-add myself, still can't log in.  I delete and recreate my account with all the necessary permissions, still can't log in.  I even tried the builtin domain admin account, that can't log in either, same message.

What is happening and how do I get back into the machine??

Comment: is there a local account on it that you can try?  Can you remotely manage it with Computer Management MMC?  Can you log in locally at the console?

Comment: I have to wait until the person who installed the OS comes in to find the local admin account but that doesn't really address the issue.  I am not able to manage it remotely with Computer Management MMC, tells me access denied (which there should be no way since I am a domain admin).  I also don't have the ability to log in locally, it is located in a server room far away, but again that wouldn't really address the issue if I could.  I need to be able to log in remotely.

Comment: If you are getting access denied, it might have an issue with its computer account and trust with the domain.  "netdom verify /d:domainname.com servername" from a DC should let you know for sure.

Comment: Are you a local server admin or domain admin?

Comment: Kim - I am a domain admin.

TheCleaner - It is very specifically telling me I am not in the RDU group, which I am.  I did the command you suggested from a domain controller and got the response: "the secure channel from computername to the domain domainname has been verified.  The connection is with the machine domaincontroller. The command completed successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the domain administrator made changes to the domain's group policy such that when you attempted to log in again, your session was loaded with the a new group policy that restricted access unless you're in the Remote Desktop users group. Or you may have been removed from the Remote Desktop users group.

To remedy the situation, I will ask for the credentials for the local administrator account and log in to the machine using those credentials. Instead of logging in with the domain, I will key in BUILTIN\administrator (usually, that is the default name of the local administrator account) and log in accordingly with the requested credentials.

Comment: I am the domain administrator and I made no such changes, also I came on to a team with little passdown and things were not documented very well before me.  What I'm left with is no idea what the local administrator password is.